# Huge MFT and slow performance

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, performance, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with huge MFT and slow performance when listing file in folder. Filesystem is about 350.000 files but in past many millions file was created and delete with crap Backup program.

System is vm on hyperv server core 2016 with raid 1 array on adaptec 6405 and Intel s3610 ssd. Vm disk is 320GB. On host test array with diskspd and performance is right. Also move vm on other host and see same problem

When run wiztree, that list file scanning only MFT, it hang after a while and use all CPU while windirstat seem faster and not hangh. 
When run contig.exe to try defrag $mft disk read and write max at about 5mb/s and system is completely freezing, cannot open neither taskmgr.
Defrag.exe analysis only require about 10 minutes to run with high cpu usage all time.

Defrag report:
 MFT size 28.32GB
 MFT records 29700863
 MFT usage 100%
 MFT fragments 143

Can huge size or 100% usage of MTF can be the problem here? I see many post about shrink and compact MFT but with no definite answer, is possible to do it and with tools can?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's ``defrag`` command to defrag a disk. You can run an analyze and post back the report. Might take a while if there are (were) tens of millions of files. I think the MFT is always shown being 100%, not a problem.

Comment: You are right, usage 100% is absolute no problem, huge size instead seem to slow down system. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solve problem with Paragon Hard Disk Manager:
First run the "Compact and Trim MFT" then "MFT defrag". 
Now MFT size is only 453MB, and usage is 100% but system is more fast when browse and search files. wiztree complete analisys in 3 seconds and defrag analisys require only 20 seconds.